# How do I remove a #idname .classname { } inside a style tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not really sure how to word it but here is the CSS code I'm working with.

```html
<style>
#st_advanced_menu_wrap .m_alignment_0 .advanced_style_wide,
#st_advanced_menu_wrap .m_alignment_3 .advanced_style_wide {
  left:0;
}
</style>
```

How do I go about calling the whole thing using the jquery **$('.className').removeClass('className');** when the piece of style code is using more than one ID AND Class? How do I reference all of that within the **'.className'** part of the jquery code? I want to remove this piece of code from a document that cannot be modified or edited internally. I can only add on to the existing code. I'm pretty new to how jquery works. Thanks!

Comment: jQuery doesn't select styles.  It selects dom elements.  So if you want to select elements that are affected by those two styles, you already have what your selectors would be.  They match exactly what the css rules are.

Comment: If you are wanting to modify a stylesheet with jQuery I would argue against it.  Rather than trying to alter the stylesheet, change the elements so that they no longer match the css rule(s).  Or you can add inline styling that overrides the css rule(s).

Comment: For an element to be affected by those rules, it has to match them. Remove any of those classes, or that top id, and they will not match the rule anymore.  To set inline styling you can use the `css()` method.

Comment: It's not clear why `$('.className').removeClass('className');` doesn't work. Example, `$('.advanced_style_wide').removeClass(advanced_style_wide');` should make the posted CSS rule unused...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to add and remove classes & ID's with jQuery

```js
$('.addColor').on("click", function(){
 $('.box').addClass("blue")
})

$('.removeColor').on("click", function(){
 $('.box').removeClass("blue")
})

$('.addId').click(function(e){
    $(".box").attr("id", "yellow");
});

$('.removeID').click(function(e){
    $('.box').removeAttr('id');
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>

<br />

<button class="addColor">Click to add class</button>

<br /><br />

<button class="removeColor">Click remove class</button>

<br /><br />

<button class="addId">Click add an ID (yellow)</button>

<br /><br />

<button class="removeID">Click remove an ID</button>
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/thmskwp5/1/)

Comment: yea but it doesn't help removing this piece of code within the style tag that has both ID and Class names. Would I remove it by doing **$('.className','#idName').removeClass('className','idName');**?

Comment: You don't have to do it one line, just do one at a time. Remove the ID's with `removeAttr` and the classes with `removeClass`, like I used in my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert another `<style>` element into the page overriding the values of the previous one.

Although not best practice, you can use the `!important` flag to ensure your rules take preference

```
var myStyle = '\
    #st_advanced_menu_wrap .m_alignment_0 .advanced_style_wide,\
    #st_advanced_menu_wrap .m_alignment_3 .advanced_style_wide { \
        left:auto!important;\
    }';
$('body').append($('<style>'+myStyle+'</style>'));
```

The backslashes `\` are only used to increase code readability

Otherwise you can change the elements class from `.advanced_style_wide` to something else, or remove the class using jQuery's `.removeClass('.advanced_style_wide')` which should stop the rules from your question effecting it

Comment: do I use the .removeClass() by itself inside a script tag?